# QTP dll library - Parameters

Tags: c#, .net, vbscript, qtp

Good afternoon all,

I am currently working on an integrated testing portal using MVC.Net.

I am attempting to migrate a VB custom communication script to a C# service.  I have successfully migrated a number of newer QTP scripts, however have got stuck on a couple of legacy scripts that the comapny requires.

The QTP script itself loads ok up to the point where a custom param is set using the following VB lines of code:

```vb
Set oParameters = oQTPApplication.Test.ParameterDefinitions.GetParameters()
oParameters.Item("sEnvironment").Value = sEnvironmentForDataTable
```

Once the code runs through the various other set ups (after successfully opening and connecting to QTP, and hits the converted lines:

**Method 1:**

```
var parameters = this.Connection.Test.ParameterDefinitions.GetParameters();
parameters["sEnvironment"].Value = this.Test.TestEnvironment;
```

**Method 2:**

```
this.Connection.Test.ParameterDefinitions["sEnvironment"].DefaultValue = this.Test.TestEnvironment;
```

**Both throw the exception:**

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>
> Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002802B (TYPE_E_ELEMENTNOTFOUND))
>
> At System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
> At QTObjectModelLib.ParameterDefinitions.get_Item(Object Position)
> At TestLayer.Tests.Utilities.Qtp5Connection.SetTestSpecificParams()

It seems that the interface is attempting to find the specified parameter, however in this case I already know it doesnt exist and wish it to add the param. to be used within the script but for the life of me - I cant find a way of adding a custom param in C#.  I assum this was working as the VB works...

Any help would be much appretiated.

Comment: Sorry, have just re-read and just to confirm - the current VB script does work with the custom param, it it the attempted migration C# solution that is causing the exception

Answer (score 0):

I have continued working on the problem since I posted and have found a solution.

You do indeed use **Method 1** however you need to ensure that the intended script has been opened.  I am assuming that the QTP script that you are connecting to needs to be set up to recieve the param.

So here are the following steps that I have taken in code to achieve this:

1. Open the QTP connection
2. Open the QTP script
3. Set up recovery and resources - inc param(s)
4. Run the test

I hope that this will be of some use to someone else in this situation.